# R - Subset a matrix in function of a variable from data frame and values of an other matrix

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, subset, adjacency-matrix

Since a few days I’m searching the way to manage my data in R. I have the same set of individuals (n=5013) structured as follow: two asymmetric adjacency matrices (`m1` and `m2`) (nxn square matrices where all the individuals compose rows and columns of matrices) and a data frame (`df`) with my set of individuals (`df$N`) and one variable (`df$V`).

I’m searching the way to subset the matrices using the variable `df$V` (different criteria/variable values for rows and cols) and subset `m1` (or identify invalid cases) in function of the cell values of `m2`.

The following example illustrates my problem:

```
# N are individuals. Two matrices (m1 and m2) and a dataframe (df) with a variable (df$V)
> df
  N  V
1 a v1
2 b v2
3 c v3
4 d v1
5 e v2
6 f v3
7 g v1

> m1
  a b c d e f g
a 7 3 9 8 1 6 8
b 1 6 9 2 9 4 4
c 2 3 2 7 9 7 3
d 9 7 6 3 2 6 6
e 9 9 6 5 5 6 5
f 1 1 1 6 1 5 9
g 6 2 5 2 1 8 5

> m2
  a b c d e f g
a 8 3 7 8 4 3 2
b 2 8 4 2 7 7 2
c 8 3 1 6 9 9 4
d 7 3 6 7 4 9 5
e 5 8 7 1 7 6 6
f 9 6 8 9 6 6 2
g 4 8 8 1 9 7 3
```

For example, I subset the cells in the matrices where rows takes the values “v1” and “v3” and cols takes values “v2” in df$V

```
> m1subseted
  b e
a 3 1
c 3 9
d 7 2
f 1 1
g 2 1
> m2subseted
  b e
a 3 4
c 3 9
d 3 4
f 6 6
g 8 9
```

and then in m1-subseted subset the observations (or identify invalid cases) that has a cell value “<5” in m2-subseted. The result I’m searching: a matrix, subset of m1.

```
#subset m1 if cell value in m2 is <5 / Invalid cells = NA
  b e
a 3 1
c 3 NA
d 7 2
f NA NA
g NA NA
```

## Reproducible data

```
m1 <- as.matrix(data.frame(a = sample(1:10, size = 7),
                 b= sample(1:10, size = 7),
                 c=sample(1:10, size = 7),
                 d=sample(1:10, size = 7),
                 e=sample(1:10, size = 7),
                 f=sample(1:10, size = 7),
                 g=sample(1:10, size = 7)))
                 rownames(m1)<-colnames(m1)


m2 <- as.matrix(data.frame(a = sample(1:10, size = 7),
                 b= sample(1:10, size = 7),
                 c=sample(1:10, size = 7),
                 d=sample(1:10, size = 7),
                 e=sample(1:10, size = 7),
                 f=sample(1:10, size = 7),
                 g=sample(1:10, size = 7)))
                 rownames(m2)<-colnames(m2)



df <- data.frame(N = as.factor(letters[1:7]), 
       V = c("v1","v2","v3","v1","v2","v3","v1"))
```

## Comment

The solution proposed by @jkt works fine, except when labels are complex (with accent marks, parentheses, etc.), as in my original dataset. The solution I find is to change the complex labels by simplest ones before apply algorithms, and restore the original labels on the result.
I share the code I used with the solution provided by @jkt (adapted to the example) in the hope that it can be useful to someone.

```
#Create new labels. In this case are numbers, where 7 
#correspond to the dimmensions of matrices and observations on df
new.code.labels<-c(1:7)
#Create new col/variable on df
df$TempLabel<-new.code.labels
#Recode rows and cols on matrices
rownames(m1)<-new.code.labels
colnames(m1)<-new.code.labels
rownames(m2)<-new.code.labels
colnames(m2)<-new.code.labels

#Apply algorithm proposed by @jkt
crit1 <- c('v1','v3')
crit2 <- 'v2'
#Observe I use new labels on dataframe (df$TempLabel)
m11 <- m1[df$TempLabel[which(df$V %in% crit1)], df$TempLabel[which(df$V %in% crit2)]]
m21 <- m2[df$TempLabel[which(df$V %in% crit1)], df$TempLabel[which(df$V %in% crit2)]]
m11[!(m21<5)] <- NA
m11

#To regain the original labels on results
row.coded.labels.result<-rownames(m11)
df.subseted.by.result.row<-subset(df, df$TempLabel %in% row.coded.labels.result)
rownames(m11)<-df.subseted.by.result.row$N

col.coded.labels.result<-colnames(m11)
df.subseted.by.result.col<-subset(df, df$TempLabel %in% col.coded.labels.result)
colnames(m11)<-df.subseted.by.result.col$N
m11
```

Comment: What is `N` in the 'df'?  Does it correspond to rownames of 'm1/m2'?

Comment: also it would help to provide a reproducible example...with actual data or analogous data

Comment: Hi @akrun. N are the labels and they correspond to rownames and colnames of m1/m2
Hi @CyrusMohammadian. This is the code I used to create the example
`N <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g") # My population
V <-c("v1","v2","v3","v1", "v2", "v3", "v1") #The variable
m1 <- matrix(sample.int(9, size = 7*7, replace = TRUE), nrow=7, ncol=7)
m2 <- matrix(sample.int(9, size = 7*7, replace = TRUE), nrow=7, ncol=7)
colnames(m1)<-N
rownames(m1)<-N
colnames(m2)<-N
rownames(m2)<-N
df<-data.frame(N,V)`
Thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use a series of subsetting commands.

This defines the two criteria (based on v1, v3 and v2):

```
crit1 <- c('v1','v3')
crit2 <- 'v2'
```

This subsets the matrices based on the criteria and the corresponding row/column names:

```
m11 <- m1[df$N[which(df$V %in% crit1)], df$N[which(df$V %in% crit2)]]
m21 <- m2[df$N[which(df$V %in% crit1)], df$N[which(df$V %in% crit2)]]
```

This sets all those values `NA` that do not meet your last criterion within the second subset matrix.

```
m11[!(m21<5)] <- NA
```

Calling `m11` then gives you:

```
   b  e
a  3  1
c  3 NA
d  7  2
f NA NA
g NA NA
```

You could turn this into a function with all your criteria as arguments plus the matrices and the dataframe.

Comment: It works nicely! Thank you very much for your help!
Just a comment: Labels in my dataset are more complex (with accent marks, parentheses, commas and so on), and this solution generates errors in the result. Obviously, a solution to this problem is to replace the complex labels by simple labels (like numbers) on the original dataset, and after operations (in the result), replace the simple labels by the original labels. 
I share the code I used (adapted to our example) in my answer (Is too long for a comment). I hope it can be useful to someone.